# Performing the appropriate join operation between two pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, join, dataframe

```
nocity.head()      

    user_id                 business_id             stars

0   cjpdDjZyprfyDG3RlkVG3w  uYHaNptLzDLoV_JZ_MuzUA  5
1   bjTcT8Ty4cJZhEOEo01FGA  uYHaNptLzDLoV_JZ_MuzUA  3
2   AXgRULmWcME7J6Ix3I--ww  uYHaNptLzDLoV_JZ_MuzUA  3
3   oU2SSOmsp_A8JYI7Z2JJ5w  uYHaNptLzDLoV_JZ_MuzUA  4
4   0xtbPEna2Kei11vsU-U2Mw  uYHaNptLzDLoV_JZ_MuzUA  5
```

---

```
withcity.head()

    business_id             city

0   YDf95gJZaq05wvo7hTQbbQ  Richmond Heights
1   mLwM-h2YhXl2NCgdS84_Bw  Charlotte
2   v2WhjAB3PIBA8J8VxG3wEg  Toronto
3   CVtCbSB1zUcUWg-9TNGTuQ  Scottsdale
4   duHFBe87uNSXImQmvBh87Q  Phoenix
```

`nocity` dataframe has `business_id`, (they may be repeating since it also has the rating each `user_id` gave for each `business_id`)

The `withcity` dataframe has the `city` associated with each `business_id`

**The result I want is:**

This is going to be super hard to word:

I want to look up the `city` associated with each `business_id` from the `withcity` dataframe and create a new column in `nocity` called `cityname`, which now has the city name associated with that `business_id`

---

**Why I gave up trying and came here**

I know this can be performed with some sort of join operation.. But I don't understand which one exactly.. I looked them up online and got a little confused as to what would happen if some `business_id` wasn't available in the two dataframes when performing that join operation?

For example:

`withcity` has some `business_id` with some `city` value; and when performing whichever appropriate join with the `nocity`, it does not find that particular `business_id`

So I came here for help.

---

**What other alternative did I try?**

```
area_dict = dict(zip(withcity.business_id, withcity.city))

emptylist = []


for rows in nocity['business_id']:

    for key, value in area_dict.items():

        if(key == rows):
            emptylist.append(value)
```

I created a dictionary which held the `business_id` and the `city` from the `withcity` dataframe, and performed some sort of matching comparison with the `nocity` dataframe.

But my method, will probably take a lot of time since there are 4.7 million records to be exact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html)

```
nocity.merge(withcity,on='business_id',how='left')
Out[855]: 
                  user_id             business_id  stars city
0  cjpdDjZyprfyDG3RlkVG3w  uYHaNptLzDLoV_JZ_MuzUA      5  NaN
1  bjTcT8Ty4cJZhEOEo01FGA  uYHaNptLzDLoV_JZ_MuzUA      3  NaN
2  AXgRULmWcME7J6Ix3I--ww  uYHaNptLzDLoV_JZ_MuzUA      3  NaN
3  oU2SSOmsp_A8JYI7Z2JJ5w  uYHaNptLzDLoV_JZ_MuzUA      4  NaN
4  0xtbPEna2Kei11vsU-U2Mw  uYHaNptLzDLoV_JZ_MuzUA      5  NaN
```

Comment: Does not address key error. OP wants actual city name not NaN see below for full answer

Comment: @codebrotherone NaN here , because we do not have the the full data set, the data he provided does not match on business_id

Comment: Aha my fault then. I thought it could have been attributed to data error. I really wish SO had a way of easily storing datasets used in questions like this. I suppose a link would do just fine

Answer (score 0):

In general, whenever you have a situation like this you want to **consider avoiding loops and iterations** and instead perform a **merge**. Then **afterwards**, you massage the data to fit your needs. For example, Wen's solution is the most apt way to do this.

However there were a few things I would add. Say those are my two dfs below:

[image: NOCITY DF]

[image: WITHCITY DF]

Let's call the first and second dfs, **nocity and withcity respectively**.

You want to do:

```
nocity.merge(withcity, on='business_id', how='left')
```

However, if you end up getting nan values as Wen got above. **Check the datatypes of your keys**

Meaning, if you business_id field in nocity was int (for some reason) while the business_id field in withcity was str then Pandas will have issues merging the dataframes and you get NaN values instead of the desired City Name.

To check you would do

```
#for all datatypes in the nocity df
print(nocity.dtypes)
#or just for the field's dtypes
print(nocity.business_id.dtypes)
```

Then you would convert to a common datatype like str if they were different...

```
#example conversion of pandas column (series) to different datatype
nocity.business_id = nocity.business_id.astype(str)
withcity.business_id = withcity.business_id.astype(str)

#then perform merge as usual
nocity = nocity.merge(withcity, on='business_id', how='left')
```

[image: Merge Results]

Hope this helps. Also don't forget to change your name from 'city' to 'cityname' if that is what you prefer

```
nocity.rename(columns = {'city': 'city name'})
```